# How to make a Vuetify list, with several columns, responsive?

Tags: vuetify.js

I have a v-list consisting of seven columns of varying width. It looks good on desktop but there isn't enough space on a mobile browser.  I'd like the columns to automatically form two rows (of three and four columns) if the viewport is small, so that each column shows its full content.
Example on the [Vuetify playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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) - reduce the window width to see what I mean.

If I use `cols="auto"` instead of `cols="2"` etc, I get almost what I need, but there is a lot of wasted space between the columns and (more importantly) betwen the two rows which are formed when it's a small viewport - this space appears to be bigger than the space between successive data rows. Another playground [here](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#eNq1VD1v2zAQ/SsHDh6K2pLjIaiiCujebt3qDpRER4dSpEqe5LiG/3uPlGMrCtIhTQzbAk/v3bsv3o+j8K5KvnTdauiVyEROqu20JFVsDUA+LDV6Ao1G+c9bQY1TaiugVsYjHdhS2baTFW1FxF8YS2Q/MCx31jEIAQ18Yl72SwUSXuCR4Oz+coyGymrgX1CUPdkJ+hHQYAce/yhG+FZqzb6ZEMVK3YcQB+lQGmKD7SnEX8/cAByPgB9u4HTK0jRPRq9TxDSo8NrqNwjzGpfSauBCc1yz2Gdh5r6TBiotfWyBeqAlud5UzGWqp4MO/vdYU5PB+jbtHp65AO6YJzSS0JqYN2edJ8HxU+DTDM41+c86xMyLhSl9d3eWhlazerS/ge9LDWIZM7BOmvtQx7wsFr107m5Rh/88KYvY83Uas38v/XMXx/najJV+nRZ8VbJW7pXjV5J5efqut2J+c+Ik8XGdps8G6Zt1ahU/80FhsX/kF87Taz5dE0vfl4Sk1ZVefG/QA39/94wACdqa+7iFwO4gXAHYN1g10MoD7JBbQHt7pbOSD4ovSzxuqylo3HhnCx/yZLILxemj2Kw2q1sxPm824udfL5+KVg==). What classes would I need to correct this?

```html
<template>
  <v-list lines="three" density="compact">
    <v-list-item v-for="i in 9" :key="i">
      <v-row no-gutters>
        <v-col cols="1">
          <v-chip size="small" color="blue" variant="outlined">
            {{ i*2 }}:00</v-chip
          >
        </v-col>
        <v-col cols="3">
          <v-chip size="small" variant="elevated" color="blue">
            <span class="text-truncate" style="width: 170px">
              destination {{ i }}</span
            >
          </v-chip>
        </v-col>
        <v-col cols="1">
          <small>&nbsp;{{ i }} ml</small>
        </v-col>
        <v-col cols="2">
          <small style="color: orange"><b>&uarr;&darr;</b>{{ i*10}}</small>
        </v-col>
        <v-col cols="1">
          <small style="color: blue"> {{ i*3 }}</small>
        </v-col>
        <v-col cols="2"> Leader </v-col>
        <v-col cols="2">
          <v-btn size="small" variant="outlined" color="blue" width="100">
            More......
          </v-btn>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
      <v-list-item-subtitle
        >This is quite a long line of text which may fill two
        rows</v-list-item-subtitle
      >
    </v-list-item>
  </v-list>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

v-col has [props](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-col/#props) for setting the number of columns based on breakpoints, `sm`, `md`, `lg`, `xl`, `xxl`

The props work as "greater than or equal to" so if `md` is the largest breakpoint you set, then the v-col will use that number of columns for medium **and larger** sized screens. `cols` is the default size and should be used to set the columns for screen sizes smaller than your smallest chosen breakpoint. The breakpoint sizes are noted on the [Vuetify grids documentation page](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/grids/#usage)

Example:

```html
<v-col cols="3" md="2" xl="1">
```

For any screen sizes below the medium breakpoint v-col will use 3 columns of width.  For medium and up to xl (i.e. medium and large) it will use 2 columns, and for xl or larger it will use 1 column.

A single row can have at most 12 columns of width, so if on small screens you want your 7 v-cols split into two rows of 3 and 4, assign 12 columns of width to the first 3 v-cols, and 12 columns to the next 4 v-cols.

[Updated Vuetify Playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

Comment: Thank you. I had read about the breakpoint sizes but didn't work out how to use them. So `cols="2" sm="1" ` really means `cols=sm?"1":"2"`, they don't work as separate props